Failure to display dynamic information from the database in fancytree
I entered fancyTree into apex and when I use static data, the tree is displayed well, but I want the data to be displayed from the database, and for this I created a restful api that outputs json, but when the url is displayed in the field I put javascript, it doesn't show anything! Why is it like that? What should I do to fix it?
This is my javascript code:
    $("#tree1").fancytree({
  checkbox: true,
  selectMode: 3,
  source: {
    url:
      "http://localhost:5080/ords/test/fancyTree/api"
  },
   lazyLoad: function(event, data) {
    data.result = {url: "http://localhost:5080/ords/test/fancyTree/api"};
  }, 
});

This is a simple query:
select 
    id as key
    ,code ||'-' || name as title
from  vE5ProcessTreeLight 
start with id=15095794414151206135  connect by   nocycle prior id=  parent_id
order siblings by eqptype,name


Are you seeing any errors in the browser console? Note, that FancyTree will not render correctly if the response structure is different from what is required. Check the API response in Postman.

No, no error is displayed. I also tested with postman, the json output is correct, but nothing is displayed in the tree. An example of json displayed in postman

"items": [
{
"key": 28337792853151002471,
"title": "040201049-040201049",
"lazy": "true"
},
{
"key": 30507792854151002661,
"title": "040221013-040221013",
"lazy": "true"
}
],
"first": {
"$ref": "http://localhost:5080/ords/test/fancyTree/api"
},
"next": {
"$ref": "http://localhost:5080/ords/test/fancyTree/api?page=1"
}
}

Hard to say whats wrong without seeing your complete implementation. Can you create a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com ? Log into workspace SO_HELP with username/pwd SO_79104475/SO_79104475 and create a new app with a page that works with static data and a page using the rest endpoint. That way anyone can have a look at your code.
